# how to capture frames every 5 seconds from real time video in swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation, intervals, image-capture

I'm new to swift and want to analyze the image from a real-time video, but most answers explained how to capture each frame of video, the code is below, I want to extract image every 5(or N) seconds, how to revise the code.

```
   func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[unowned self] in
            guard let uiImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `AVAssetImageGenerator` to extract image frames.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could keep track of the elapsed time yourself by doing something like this?

```
var lastSampleDate = Date.distantPast
let sampleInterval: TimeInterval = 5 // 5 seconds

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    guard currentDate.timeIntervalSince(lastSampleDate) >= sampleInterval else {
        return
    }

    lastSampleDate = currentDate
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        guard let uiImage = self.imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not simply timeIntervalSinceNow?

Comment: @LeoDabus that would also work, but you need to instantiate a `Date` anyway to assign to `lastSampleDate`